# c# check if a given file path contains a root directory

Tags: c#, file, path, directory, arguments

how can i check if a given file path for a console application contains a root directory? for example, the person inputs the argument value "false" for an argument that is looking for a path. It will create the path to the default directory "false" folder. Instead I want it to only accept the argument if the provided argument is in the form of eg "C:\newproject". How should I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.ispathrooted.aspx):

```
if(Path.IsPathRooted(path))...
```